# Docker running test with nodejs and volume

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm learning docker and I'm having some troubles with the volume in a development environment with Nodejs.

I having the following simple dockerfile that aims to start my unit tests from a NodeJS parent image:

```
FROM node:4-onbuild

VOLUME ["/usr/src/app"]

CMD [ "npm", "test" ]
```

I'm running my container this way:

```
docker run -v /C/Users/myUser/dockertest:/usr/src/app notest
```

But I keep receiving the following error:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@2.15.9
npm info using node@v4.5.0
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.15-moby
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "test"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/src/app/npm-debug.log
```

I don't understand why I'm not able to find the package.json file inside of the `/usr/src/app` folder inside of my container.

The fact is that if I'm using the following docker file :

```
FROM node:4-onbuild

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

CMD [ "npm", "test" ]
```

My tests will be running in the container, but only after building step (so I have to build each time I make a modification...) . I need to play these tests any time I want, by launching a docker command (restart ? exec ?) quickly

Thanks for your help

Comment: i think volumes are getting linked on container start. So your WORKDIR is actually not the linked volume as its created on image build and therefore empty.

Comment: Even on the first case ? What should I do to make the first dockerfile working ?

Comment: why dont you use COPY to insert your sourcecode instead of linking it?

Comment: I don't want to docker build each time I make a modification on my codebase

Comment: what you can do is copy everything build relevant (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

You want to COPY everything build relevant and link your codebase on containerstart.

```
FROM node:4.4

# Enviroment variables
ENV HOMEDIR /data
RUN mkdir -p ${HOMEDIR}
WORKDIR ${HOMEDIR}

# install all dependencies
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install

# add node content initially
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "test"]
```

And then link it on start:

```
version: '2'
services:
  myApp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: "myApp"
    volumes:
      - .:/data
```

You should now be able to change your codebase without restarting/rebuilding your container.

Comment: I m probably missing something. I m always having to remove containers, rebuild and run (taking time and multiple command lines). Not what I m looking for